# NextJS pure SSR - storing/sharing data across components

Tags: caching, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm using NextJS with App Router, and I have an app that works exclusively with SSR. But it also works with user data, and it looks tedious to me to have to query the backend for user data on every new page - so I would like to store it somewhere.

I'm fairly certain I can't use `localStorage` or `useState` since I assume they require `use client`. It's unclear to me if `zustand`/`jotai` could cover this use-case, their docs (even the SSR pages) aren't clear and most of the time seem to me to be suggesting that their usage requires a `use client` context eventually.

The pattern looks like this:

1. Call backend API to fetch user data.
2. Store user data somewhere (cache? state?) *without ever using the `use client` directive*.
3. Be able to fetch data from this store, whatever it is, from any component regardless of its relationship to the component that put the data into the store.

How it might look in code (the below pattern is translated from `django`):

```js
// # app/somewhere/page.ts
// "use client" is not and should not be set
const auth_id = await getAuth();
const user_data = await fetch('api.com/users/`${auth_id}`');
setCache(`${user_data.id}`, user_data);

// # app/elsewhere/page.ts
// "use client" is not and should not be set
const auth_id = await getAuth();
const user_data = getCache(`${user_data.id}`);
```

Searching for caching or state management inside SSR leads to endless resources about how to store or cache things (especially pages) *for the client*, but not arbitrary data internal to the server.

Is this pattern possible? It doesn't have to look like the code I suggested, as long as it fulfills the requirements.